# Tiny R plot window

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, window, xps, r

Producing `R` plots in a new Dell XPS-13-9310 running Ubuntu 20.04 opens tiny windows. Here is a screenshot of the phenomenon: [image]

Resizing the window will not increase the size of axis labels proportionately. I tried tweaking the Settings>Displays resolution with only slight improvement---while bigger, the plot window remains much smaller than in my older XPS-13 with 16.04.

The display is high-def LCD:
13.4" OLED 3.5K (3456x2160) InfinityEdge Touch Anti-Reflective 400-Nit Display

Any ideas where I might point my inquiries?

Comment: You can't change the size of the plot window by simply resizing with the mouse.  R isn't a what-you-see-is-what-you-get program.  Instead, if you have define (programmatically, in the interactive window) how big it is.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075435/how-to-change-plot-size-in-r) for an example.

Comment: Add information of your resolution: I can guess now that you have an Ultra HD display.

Comment: Indeed @vanadium. I've added the info

Comment: For me, resizing the window resizes the plot.